# How does the ng-invalid-parse class get added to form

Tags: angularjs

I am using a custom angular directive for validation of a field in a form.

When one of the validation fails, along with the custom error, the class `ng-invalid-parse` is also added to the field.

Is it normal behavior?  If so, what causes it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ng-invalid-parse` gets added when a parser returns undefined, no validation will be called after that.

More info: [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: Yes. But I could not find the same behaviour in the plunker attached on angular docs page . http://plnkr.co/edit/gRtAwHXo1bBGtsdNoVcq?p=preview

Comment: This behavior was added in angular 1.3. The above plunk uses older version, hence, parse error is not reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

Found this because my validation was correct, but the `ng-invalid` class was still being applied because `ng-invalid-parse` was being applied.

In my (simple) case I was validating an ipv4 address, and simply had failed to return the value:

```
angular.module('insightApp.directives').directive('ipInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      if (!(ctrl)) {
        return;
      }

      function ipValidator(ngModelValue) {
        if (
          ngModelValue != '0.0.0.0' &&
          ngModelValue != '255.255.255.255' &&
          ngModelValue.match(/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/)
        ) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('ipValidator', true);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('ipValidator', false);
        }

        // Adding this return statement resolved the problem with "ng-invalid-parse" being added
        return ngModelValue;
      }

      ctrl.$parsers.push(ipValidator);
    }
  }
});
```