# How the ng-valid-parse is set in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive to format the date. It should return the error information like ng-invalid when the format of input goes wrong. Now it can set ng-invalide in this case, but it also set **ng-valid-parse** if the format of input is wrong. In my opinion, as the format goes wrong, it is not valide.

So here comes my question : how the ng-valid-parse is set ?

```
myDirectives.directive('myDateFormat', function ($window) {
'use strict';
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        // other codes ...

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var date = moment(viewValue, dateFormat);
            if(date && date.isValid()){
                return date.toDate();
            }else{
                ctrl.$setValidity('myDateFormat', false);
                return ""; // or it should return false here?
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look back to my question after 5 month, I found this similar question [How do ng-invalid-parse gets added to form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28237075/1165178).

Even though I set the validity to false : `ctrl.$setValidity('myDateFormat', false);`, but the `$parsers` return a **non undefined** object. It means that the parsing is valid, so the `ng-valid-parse` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom parse validator to the ngModelController:

```
ctrl.$validators.parse = function(modelValue, viewValue){
  return (modelValue instanceof Date)&&!isNaN(modelValue.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. In fact, I just want to know why the ng-parse-valide is set even though I set validity to false. But your answer still give me a hint, which is the `$parsers` do the parsing job, the `validators` valide.